# PHP Redirect to custom url

Tags: php, sqlite

Good day!

I'm new to PHP and I just wanted to know, I'm creating a list of customers from the database directly and showing them on the website. Each customer name is an anchor tag that should lead to a specific url for this customer only, in order to display their expenses, for example expenses.php/johndoe...or something like that...

I'm able to show the customers with anchor tags on the page with the code below, but how can I do something like this with PHP?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        table {
            margin:0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>

<?php 

class Users extends SQLite3 {
    function __construct() {
        $this->open("customers.db");
    }
}

$db = new Users();

if (!$db) {
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} else {
    echo "";
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS";

$result = $db->query($sql);
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>

";
while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='customerExpenses.php'>" . $row['NAME'] . "</a></td>";
    echo "<tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
$db->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the parameter on the href, I have used `id` assuming you have one of those on the table.

```
echo "<td><a href='customerExpenses.php?id=$row[id]'>$row[NAME]</a></td>";
```

Also you are missing `</tr>` after `echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th>` so amend to

```
echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th></tr>";
//                            ^^^^^
```

Also you need to move these line

```
</body>
</html>
```

to the end of the page as you are now outputting things in the PHP section that belong inside the `<body>`

Comment: Yep! I do have an id in my database. Even though the url gets changed with the clicked client's id, I should have another page were they get redirected based on that specific need shouldn't I?

Comment: Yes, you have to write a `customerExpenses.php` script, that expects to get passed `id` in the `$_GET` array - `$GET_['id']` and in there you query the db based on knowing who the user is and show whatever other data the page was designed for

Comment: Sorry thats `$_GET['id']`